# git pull broke something - how to go back to previous working commit and merge the remote changes in again?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull

I commited a new feature locally, pulled from remote and got merge conflicts. After resolving them, my feature stopped working (seems like I made an error).

My idea was to go back to my commit and somehow repeat the merge. I checked out my commit, made a new branch, checked out master and tried to merge the new branch into master. This didn't work because "Everything is up to date".

How do I best handle this if I don't want to fix the error by looking through the code by hand?

**/edit**: I accepted the correct answer to the question but it turns out that my problem has a different origin than assumed above. I asked a follow-up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65391983/why-did-git-pull-change-my-code-without-throwing-merge-conflicts-for-all-changes).

Comment: The fact that you got the message "Everything is up to date" is that you failed to go back to the original commit before the pull to create your branch.  You need to do that.

Comment: "My idea was to go back to my commit and somehow repeat the merge" So just reset hard to the commit before the merge commit. Now the merge commit is gone and you are ready to merge from the remote tracking branch again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do the checkout of your commit *after* the first merge to master, you will get an "Everything is up to date" when merging from `master`.

```
m--m--m
       \
 f--f1--F
      \
       newBranch: master is already merged
```

You need, as commented, to `reset --hard` to f1, and retry the merge.
As long as you don't push, you can reset/retry as many times as you need.