# Why did git pull change my code without throwing merge conflicts for all changes?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull, git-merge-conflict

I commited a new feature locally, pulled from remote and got merge conflicts. After resolving them, my feature stopped working. I assumed that I made an error and asked [a question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65384476/git-pull-broke-something-how-to-go-back-to-previous-working-commit-and-merge-t/) yesterday. So I did a hard reset to my previous commit, repeated the merge and resolved the conflicts I was shown.

But again, my feature stopped working. I looked through the code manually and saw that part of the code of my local commit was changed by the pull but no merge conflict had been displayed for this part.

So for some changes, merge conflicts were displayed but not for others. I confirmed this by reproducing the situation a third time.

What could be the cause of this behaviour?

Comment: Git being able to apply the changes without conflicts does *not* guarantee the code still works as expected afterwards. As a trivial example, imagine one commit changes which of two buggy functions gets called and the other fixes a bug the function that *used* to get called. Git can merge those happily, but overall the bug is still there. That's why testing (particularly at a high level - in that example the unit tests for the functions will still pass) is important.

Comment: Thank you very much, @jonrsharpe and VonC. Your answers improved both my understanding of git as well as of software development. :-) I think I've located the problem now: when a collaborator merged in an older part of my feature they must have rejected part of my changes. Since I didn't make these changes in my current local commit the differences to remote didn't get flagged as merge conflicts. I plan to learn about tests as soon as possible to circumvent this problem in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is about *concurrent* modification: if you have the same line in a file modified both by your branch and the remote one you are pulling from, you will get a conflict.

But if someone else has pushed to remote a "bad" code which, when pulled, get applied right away (no conflict, because you did not modify directly that part), then you will have to test the result of that pull to detect it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @VonC! With your help, I think I have located the error now. If you are interested to read it, see my top-level comment about it.

Comment: @cssdev Good catch. Tests are becoming crucial when you are doing collaborative distributed development ;)